# Regular expression for decimal separator

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression that only matches `.` and `,` as valid char single char in a input filed. I have tried:

```
^(\.\,)$
```

Comment: What about the Arabic decimal separator?

Comment: Are you wanting to match only `.` or `,`? Or do you want to match a number with separators? The title makes this a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't include the `|` character to divide your two possibilities, so it was looking for `.,`, not `.` *or* `,`. This works:

```
@"^(\.|\,)$"
```

Or you can use a class. In this context, you don't need to escape either character:

```
@"^[.,]$"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use a regular expression in the first place:

```
if(fld=='.' || fld==',') ...
```

You could use a regular expression if you insist: `[\\.,]`, but I really don't see why you would want to do that.

Comment: Sure it wold be good. This bug fix require a regular expression and write a expression every second year.

Answer (score 0):

You specified start of line and end of line, but no numbers.

This will match a number and one or no decimal points:

```
^(\d+[.,]{0,1}\d*)$
```

Comment: I guess you meant ^(\d+[.,]{0,1}\d*)$

Comment: It's setting for number format in a web program. Not actual input field for number, there are just to char thas are valid.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  Regex re = new Regex("^\d+[\.,]?\d*$");
```